# $f(Y),g(Y)\in K[Y]$ coprime $\Rightarrow f(Y)-g(Y)X$ irreducible in $K(X)[Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that $f(Y),g(Y)\in K[Y]$ coprime $\Rightarrow f(Y)-g(Y)X$ irreducible in $K(X)[Y]$ where $K$ is a field. It also states that $\deg(f(Y)g(Y))\geq1$, but doesn't that follow from the coprime statement? Doesn't even $\deg(f(Y)g(Y))\geq2$ follow? If $\deg(f(Y))=0$ for instance then is a unit, so surely divides $g(Y)$.

I tried to show that $f(Y)-g(Y)X$ is irreducible and primitive in $(K[X])[Y]$. I've wrote $f=\sum f_i Y^i, g=\sum g_i Y^i;f_i,g_i\in K$. $f(Y)-g(Y)X=\sum (f_i-g_iX)Y^i$. Now if $p$ is prime in $K[X]$ with $\forall i:p|(f_i-g_iX)$ then $0\leq \deg(p)\leq1$.

So $\deg(p)=0$ isn't possible as this would mean $\forall i\exists c_i,d_i\in K:p(c_i-d_i X)=f_i-g_iX$ but this means $p|f$ and $p|g$ in K[Y].

Case $\deg(p)=1$ means that there are $c,d\in K$ s.t. $p=(c-dX)$ ($c,d$ aren't zero, else $f,g$ couldn't be coprime). But this means that for all $i$ there is an $u_i\in K$ s.t. $u_i(c-dX)=f_i-g_iX$. But in this case $f=c\sum u_iY^i,g=d\sum u_iY^i$.

So now we know the primitive statement. For the irreducible statement I've got that if $ab=f-gX;a,b\in K[X][Y]$ then $a,b$ are primitive (Gauss lemma). I've tried to write $a=\sum a_iY^i$ and $b=\sum b_iY^i$ with $a_i,b_i\in K[X]$ but I didn't get nowhere after $a_0b_0=f_0-g_0X$ , so $a_0$ or $b_0$ has to be a unit.

Comment: I think your statement should be: it's irreducible as an element of $K[X][Y]$. This because a polynomial of degree $1$ in $F[Y]$ is irreducible if $F$ is a field, so for $F=K(Y)$.

Comment: You mean "as an element of" instead of "in"? Yes, I guess it would make it more clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(Y)-g(Y)X$ is reducible over $K(X)$, then by Gauss it is reducible over $K[X]$. So, assume that f(Y)-g(Y)X= h(X,Y)k(X,Y), where $h,k\in K[X,Y]$. Since left hand side is a linear polynomial with respect to $X$, then so is the right hand side, hence one of $h(X,Y)$ and $k(X,Y)$ is linear, say $h(X,Y)$, with respect to $X$, while the other is constant. So, we have $h(X,Y)=h_0(Y)+h_1(Y)X$ and $k(X,Y)=k(Y)$. Now, $f(Y)-g(Y)X= h_0(Y)k(Y)+h_1(Y)k(Y)X$, and since $f(Y)$ and $g(Y)$ are coprime, we get $k(Y)=k\in K$. Therefore, $f(Y)-g(Y)X$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you! At the beginning its K(X)[Y], and K[X][Y] instead of K(X), K[X]. My argument for the primitivity is correct right?

Comment: Yes, your argument seems OK. Only, if $p\in K[X]$ is prime, then $\deg(p)>0$, since otherwise is unit. That part is not correct, because a unit $p$ divides $f$ and $g$ doesn't imply a contradiction.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yeah dont know why I made the case $\deg(p)=0$.